# My Frontend (Nuxt) can't call the graphql endpoint, I'm ussing docker

Tags: docker, nginx, nuxt.js, strapi

Hi have deployed my app in pre-prod env, I have a frontend (nuxt) and backend (strapi), I'm using docker image for front, back, and Nginx.

But the frontend service can't fetch strapi graphql endpoint, but when I connect the local frontend to my pre-prod backend it works well but it isn't the same behavior with the pre-prod frontend.

i have this error when i log the front container :

```
---> ERROR >  Network error: request to https://mydomain.dev/graphql failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 161.35.150.4:443

  at new ApolloError (node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:92:26)
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1588:34
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2008:15
  at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2006:26
  at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2004:20)
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1483:29
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Error Network error: request to https://mydomain.dev/graphql failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443
 ---> ERROR >  Network error: request to https://mydomain.dev/graphql failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 161.35.150.4:443
```

nginx.conf

```
    events{}

http{
  include mime.types;

  # Expires map
  map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
      default                    off;
      text/html                  epoch;
      text/css                   max;
      application/javascript     max;
      ~image/                    max;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
    

    location / {
        return 301 https://mydomain.dev$request_uri;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name mydomain.dev;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/mydomain.dev/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/mydomain.dev/privkey.pem;
    
    location /admin {
      sendfile on;
      proxy_pass http://backend:1337;
    }
    
    location /graphql {
      sendfile on;
      proxy_pass http://backend:1337;
    }

    location / {
      sendfile on;
      proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
    }
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
# path: ./docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: mydockerhub/app-front:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: .
    image: mydockerhub/app-back
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: ${DATABASE_CLIENT}
      DATABASE_HOST: myDB
      DATABASE_PORT: ${DATABASE_PORT}
      DATABASE_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      ADMIN_JWT_SECRET: ${ADMIN_JWT_SECRET}
      APP_KEYS: ${APP_KEYS}
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
    depends_on:
      - myDB
    volumes:
      - ./app:/srv/app

  myDB:
    container_name: myDB
    platform: linux/amd64 #for platform error on Apple M1 chips
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
    volumes:
      - strapi-data:/var/lib/mysql
      #- ./data:/var/lib/mysql # if you want to use a bind folder
    ports:
      - '13306:3306'
  webserver:
    container_name: webserver
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/:ro
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro

volumes:
  strapi-data:
```

Comment: What's the error?  What endpoint are you actually trying to call?  Beyond this configuration, is there any of the front- or back-end code that would help demonstrate the problem better?

Comment: I updated the question with the error message

Comment: The error message suggests the Nginx server isn't running.  I'm guessing you're running it outside of Docker on the same host?

Comment: I run Nginx inside docker on the same host

Comment: it works when i test my local front with the pre-prod backend https://mydomain.dev/graphql but it doesn't works on the pre-prod front-end